# How to make unselected part of pie chart and bar grayed out?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to make practice from an example below:
[enter link description here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filtering-removing.html)

The link above shows when I select 2011 in pie chart, the others are grayed out. But my code doesn't make it.

The example works perfectly as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTNbP.png)

My code below couldn't make unselected part of pie chart and bar grayed out like the example demonstrate:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Removing Empty Bars</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kevinkraus92/cc5ac08b30c244e54e2c96bbe5fea110/raw/608ea6bc5564c9705a6b3c41281b5dddc84b8879/dc.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dc-js/dc.js/develop/web-src/examples/header.js"></script>
  <p>Example demonstrating using a "<a href="https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups">Fake Group</a>" to remove
    the empty bars of an ordinal bar chart when their values drop to zero.</p>

  <p>(Note the use of <code><a href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX">.elasticX(true)</a></code>
    to force calculation of the X domain each round.)</p>

<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-hist-spend"></div>
<div id="chart-row-spenders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.1.1/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var yearRingChart   = new dc.PieChart("#chart-ring-year"),
    spendHistChart  = new dc.BarChart("#chart-hist-spend"),
    spenderRowChart = new dc.RowChart("#chart-row-spenders");

// use static or load via d3.csv("spendData.csv").then(function(spendData) {/* do stuff */});
var spendData = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Year: 2013},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Year: 2013}
];

// normalize/parse data
spendData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Spent = d.Spent.match(/\d+/);
});

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}

// set crossfilter
var ndx = crossfilter(spendData),
    yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
    spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendHist    = spendDim.group().reduceCount(),
    nonEmptyHist = remove_empty_bins(spendHist)

yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);

spendHistChart
    .width(300).height(200)
    .dimension(spendDim)
    .group(nonEmptyHist)
    .x(d3.scaleBand())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);

spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base unit
spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);

spenderRowChart
    .width(350).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);

dc.renderAll();

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dc.js's CSS to get the same effects. If you want to style it, use that CSS as a starting point.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Removing Empty Bars</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dc-js/dc.js/develop/web-src/examples/header.js"></script>
  <p>Example demonstrating using a "<a href="https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups">Fake Group</a>" to remove
    the empty bars of an ordinal bar chart when their values drop to zero.</p>

  <p>(Note the use of <code><a href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX">.elasticX(true)</a></code>
    to force calculation of the X domain each round.)</p>

<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-hist-spend"></div>
<div id="chart-row-spenders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.1.1/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var yearRingChart   = new dc.PieChart("#chart-ring-year"),
    spendHistChart  = new dc.BarChart("#chart-hist-spend"),
    spenderRowChart = new dc.RowChart("#chart-row-spenders");

// use static or load via d3.csv("spendData.csv").then(function(spendData) {/* do stuff */});
var spendData = [
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$10', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$40', Year: 2011},
    {Name: 'Mr A', Spent: '$70', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$20', Year: 2012},
    {Name: 'Mr B', Spent: '$50', Year: 2013},
    {Name: 'Mr C', Spent: '$30', Year: 2013}
];

// normalize/parse data
spendData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Spent = d.Spent.match(/\d+/);
});

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}

// set crossfilter
var ndx = crossfilter(spendData),
    yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
    spendDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
    nameDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
    spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
    spendHist    = spendDim.group().reduceCount(),
    nonEmptyHist = remove_empty_bins(spendHist)

yearRingChart
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(spendPerYear)
    .innerRadius(50);

spendHistChart
    .width(300).height(200)
    .dimension(spendDim)
    .group(nonEmptyHist)
    .x(d3.scaleBand())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);

spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base unit
spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);

spenderRowChart
    .width(350).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .elasticX(true);

dc.renderAll();

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```